# How to find or remove list of substrings within a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of sub strings which I am going to remove from another list, `mylist`

```
mylist = ['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789','ghi123']

sub = ['123','456']
print ([s for s in mylist if sub[j] in s for j in sub])
```

This gives error. Is there any other way to find this.

Expected output:

```
['abc123','ghi123','def456']
```

Comment: Please post your desired output, so that you can have [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your list comp is unordered. Further more, `j` is element from `sub`, so you shouldn't be doing `sub[j]`.

Comment: On a oneliner: `print filter(lambda x: filter(lambda y : x.endswith(y), sub), mylist)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need

```
mylist = ['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789','ghi123']
sub = ['123','456']

print ([i for i in mylist for j in sub if j in i])
```

**Output:**

```
['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi123']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this

```
import re

mylist = ['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789', 'ghi123']

sub = ['123', '456']
for item in mylist:
    m = re.match(r"([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)", item)
    if m.group(2) not in sub:
        mylist.remove(item)
    print(mylist)
```